MariaDB show system variables
I've installed MariaDB 11.2.2 on Windows to play a bit with the new database system and now my confusion.
my.ini start parameters:
slow_query_log = ON
long_query_time = 0
log_slow_verbosity = ALL

Query select information_schema.system_variables.variable_name, information_schema.system_variables.default_value from information_schema.system_variables WHERE variable_name LIKE 'log_slow%' delivers:
LOG_SLOW_QUERY = OFF
LOG_SLOW_QUERY_TIME = 10.000000

Query SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES delivers:
log_slow_query= ON
log_slow_query_time = 0

Slow query log exists and logging is functional.
I thought global system variables should have the same value independently of the way how they are queried. Searching in MariaDB documentation doesn't help to understand it. Would you please push me in the right direction?
Thank you!

What is the client? It may set its own environ variables values upon the starting.. Also check [client] section of my.ini file.

Hmmm...  MySQL has moved those settings around a couple of times.  Meanwhille, I have not kept up with what MariaDB has done.  Maybe in `perfschema?

I'm afraid you are comparing two different things. The query you run against information schema checks for the default value, which is OFF and 10.
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES shows the current settings, not the default ones. This is in line with your my.ini, where you enabled slow log and set the long_query_time to 0.
For IS query you want to look for GLOBAL_VALUE column, not DEFAULT_VALUE.
Refer to this documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-system_variables-table/

Thank you! Stupid mistake causes stupid results...
